# C++. How can I free memory correctly?

Tags: c++

Written code to find and remove the largest word in a string without the using of library functions. Everything works fine. But when I want to free memory, the result is negative (displays an empty line). If you remove the call to the memory release function, everything will work correctly, but there will be a leak of memory.
How do I fix it? Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int length(char *text) // string length
{
    char *begin = text;
    while(*text++);

    return text - begin - 1;
}

int size(char **text) // size of two-dimensional array
{
    int i = 0;
    while(text[i]) i++;

    return i;
}

void free_memory(char **text)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size(text); i++)
        delete text[i];

    delete [] text;
}


char **split(char *text, char delim)
{
    int words = 1;
    int len = length(text);

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        if(text[i] == delim) words++;

    char **result = new char*[words + 1];
    int j = 0, t = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<words; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new char[len];

        while(text[j] != delim && text[j] != '\0') result[i][t++] = text[j++];

        j++;
        t = 0;
    }

    result[words + 1] = nullptr;

    return result;
}

char *strcat(char *source, char *destination)
{
    char *begin = destination;

    while(*destination) destination++;
    *destination++ = ' ';
    while(*source) *destination++ = *source++;

    return begin;
}

char *removeWord(char *in_string)
{
    char **words = split(in_string, ' ');
    int max = length(words[0]);
    int j = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<size(words); i++)
        if(max < length(words[i]))
        {
            max = length(words[i]);
            j = i;
        }

    int index;
    char *result;

    if(!j) index = 1;
    else index = 0;

    result = words[index];

    for(int i=0; i<size(words); i++)
        if(i != j && i != index)
            result = strcat(words[i], result);

    free_memory(words); // I want free memory here

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char text[] = "audi and volkswagen are the best car";

    cout << removeWord(text) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `std::string` to character arrays.

Comment: why not using "modern" containers since you're using C++: strings & vectors. No memory leaks with those.

Comment: `result[i] = new char[len];`: missing 1 byte for nul-char

Comment: The easy answer is "use `std::string`". The correct but impractical answer is "`delete` what you `new`ed and `delete []` what you `new []`ed", but it's way too annoying to keep track of, so just use `std::string` instead.

Comment: You could use smart pointers to manage your memory deallocations.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question, because even if it is perfectly reasonable to wonder about this, the whole design is completely messed up. Any answer that would answer your question would still be very bad C++ code. If you want to use this style of programming, use C. If you want to use C++, use provided containers, or at least use modern design.

Comment: Don't reuse a pointer from within the split words for the result, allocate new memory for the result and `strcat` onto that instead. And make sure to terminate your strings.

Comment: If you use `std::string` and `std::vector<std::string>`, most of your code will go away. The `length` function would be `s.length()`, the `size`would be `v.size()`, `free_memory`would not be needed, `strcat` would just be `+`, etc. You are doing *way* too much work yourself.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre TIL `std::string` and `std::vector` are "modern" ;)

Comment: it was modern in 1996 in the STL times. hence the quotes.

Comment: And BTW, you might also want to check the methods used in [How to split a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string)

Comment: The trick today in managing memory is to never write `new` or `delete` yourself.

Comment: _"Written code to find and remove the largest word in a string without the using of library functions."_ Is some computing course asking you to do this? If so, why do they think it's useful? Or at least, why are they asking for this in a C++ course, when it's just C? Seeing the sheer amount of guff that seems to be requested in people's courses makes me glad that I taught myself how to program, and to program things that I had a concrete practical need for.

Comment: Note that `strcat()`, as coded here, is an infinite loop with `strcat(foo,foo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues. First is that `result` is assigned to a memory location in `words`. Second, is that you're storing the result of `strcat` in `words[i]` which will likely not have enough room (see [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) documentation).

```
result = new char[len(in_string)+1]; // +1 for space for null char

// the old loop reversed the word order -- if you want to keep doing
// that, make this a descending loop
for(int i=0; i<size(words); i++)
    if(i != j && i != index)
        strcat(result, words[i]);

free_memory(words);

return result;
```

So that when you free `words`, what result points to is also free'd. You would then need to free your `result` in `main()`.

```
int main()
{
    char text[] = "audi and volkswagen are the best car";
    char * result = removeWord(text);
    cout << result << endl;

    delete[] result;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is C style programming - not C++. I see that your aim is to implement everything from scratch, possibly for practicing. But even then, your code is not designed/structured properly.

Besides that, you also have several bugs in your code:

1. `result[words + 1] = nullptr;` must be `result[words] = nullptr;`
2. You need `result[i][t] = '\0';` after the while loop in `split`
3. `delete text[i]` must be `delete [] text[i]`
4. You cannot assign to your `result` pointer memory from `words`, then free it and then return it for use by the caller.
5. There is at least one further bug in the second half of `removeWord`. It would be tedious to try to understand what you are trying to do there.

You might want to start with a simpler task. You also should proceed step-by-step and check each function for correctness independently first and not implement everything and then test. Also take a look at the tool valgrind for memory checking - if you use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The way you free memory correctly is to use RAII:

- Only use `new` and `new[]` in constructors
- Pair those with `delete` and `delete[]` in the corresponding destructor
- Use automatic storage duration objects as much as possible

If you are specifically not using `std::string` and `std::vector` etc, for reasons of learning pointers, you will end up writing some small number of classes that resemble `string` and `vector` and `unique_ptr`, and then you go about programming as if you were using the `std` versions.

Comment: The alternative is to replace `new type[...]` with `malloc(...)` and `delete ...` with `free(...)` and accept that you were writing C all along